# Formulas to be triggered when Excel is opened or saved

Tags: vba, excel

I have several custom-made (VBA) formulas in my Excel. Examples are

```
    = isfileExists(c3)
    = isReadOnly(c3)
```

There are multiple calls to these functions (200/column)

These are slowing down the file as they involve heavy VBA. I want the above formulas to be run only when user opens the file or saves the file only!

How can I go on to do this without touching 'enabling/disabling automatic calculations'? (Please note I do know how to write the event functions but I am looking for an idea to put inside them/anywhere)

Sample idea I have is, adding a `'` infront the formulas and whenever user opens/saves, that `'` (apostrophe) would be removed using macro; hence the formulas would calculate. Any other easier suggestions?

Thanks much!

Comment: I don't get it, why are you against events? That seems like far and away the easiest way to do this.

Comment: You can cache the formula results in a Global (or Static inside the function) dictionary object: once you've checked a file once you can use the cached result instead of repeating the file check)

Comment: Does the content of C3 (etc) change frequently?  Unless you have set your functions to be `Volatile`, the functions should only be invoked when the referenced cell changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can cache the formula results in a Global (or Static inside the function) dictionary object: once you've checked a file once you can use the cached result instead of repeating the file check)

```
Public Function ExpensiveCheck(fpath As String) As Boolean

    Static dict As Object, ans As Boolean
    'create the dictionary if not already created
    If dict Is Nothing Then
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    End If

    If Not dict.exists(fpath) Then
        ans = (Dir(fpath, vbNormal) <> "") 'do your checking here
        dict.Add fpath, ans
    End If

    ExpensiveCheck = dict(fpath)
End Function
```

The dict will be lost when the session ends, so the formula should always refresh the cache when you open the file.

Downside is you may need some mechanism to clear/refresh the cache if you want to update the output after some change in the files being checked.

Comment: That's brilliant, but I have mixed feelings about a UDF that accesses the file system. Have an upvote anyway.

Comment: This is one way to manage those concerns (if I'm understanding them correctly) - make sure it only checks once...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your UDFs to calculate along with the rest of the worksheet cells, then you don't want UDFs; make them `Private`, or stick `Option Private Module` at the top of the standard module where they're declared, to make them unavailable to use as custom worksheet functions.

Then handle `Workbook.Open` and `Workbook.BeforeSave` events, and have these two handlers call some `Private Sub` that's responsible for writing to the cells you currently have these UDFs in.

That way the values will only be computed when the workbook opens and before it's saved.

UDFs that incur disk I/O aren't ideal: keep that processing for macros.

Comment: Thanks all. I am going to go with Mat's way and move the entire UDF to macro side and make it go though columns and write values.

I will definitely have a hard look at Tim's answer tomorrow and try it out.

This file is a shared file in shared drive which is accessed by all sort of people so that does at some dynamics to it.