# Excel connection to Oracle database

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, database-connection

I have a Excel worksheet with a list of numbers (column a).  Based off that range of numbers, I need to retrieve selected columns from a table in an Oracle database and bring it back to Excel in column B.

I intend to deploy the spreadsheet with the vba code to other users, so I would I don't want a method that is hard coded to a specific computer.

I have the following information:
Oracle database name, Oracle User Name, Oracle Password, Oracle table name

I found a code online which uses uses a formula to call the vba code to connect to Oracle.  I'm getting a #Value error message when the results are returned.  There is a formula [=GetToadData(A1)] in column B1 that retrieves the lookup value in column A1.  This triggers the VBA function code to connect to Oracle and retrieve the requested data [HANDSET_SERIAL_NUMBER_NEW, SERVREQ_TRANSACTION_TS].

I'm getting #value as the formula result which means there is something wrong with with either my sql code or the connection string.  I can clarify any thing if need be.

XXXXX = user defined input

```vb
Function GetToadData(IMEI)    
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command

    Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=XXXXX;USER ID=XXXXX;PASSWORD=XXXXX"
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
    Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    Cmd.CommandText = "select HANDSET_SERIAL_NUMBER_NEW, SERVREQ_TRANSACTION_TS,  from mi_tempadm.wome_tm_data_new where HANDSET_SERIAL_NUMBER_NEW  = IMEI;"                                           

    Set RS = Cmd.Execute
    GetToadData = RS.Fields(0).Value
End Function
```

Comment: The "best" approach may vary according to your exact circumstances, but ADO is typically used for this. Plenty of examples of this to be found via Google - eg. http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?40986-Solved-Connect-to-Oracle-Database-using-Excel-VBA  Each user will need the appropriate version of the Oracle Client installed.

Comment: You need to be pretty specific about what your actual problem is in order to get useful suggestions here.

Comment: Here is the below code that i would like to use but is not working properly:

Comment: No-one can help you if you don't provide details as to *exactly* what it was you tried.  Outside of that, you're just asking for a tutorial-type answer, of which there are plenty to be found by some googling for "Excel ADO Oracle"

Comment: If you want to post code, **edit your question to add it** - don't try to put it in a comment, or post it in an answer.   You will get more useful debugging information if you call your function from a Sub instead of from a worksheet.

Comment: Hi Tim -  i have revised my question to be more specific!  Sorry for not being more clear in the first place.  First time poster :)  Just to add.  i have tried numerous methods.  the only time that i know i connected to the Oracle table correctly through Excel is via the "Getting External Data" method / Oracle Provider for OLE DB.  I know the connection works as it pulls the table.  The problem with this method is that i'm not sure how to pull only the data for the range is column A

Answer (score 0):

If your IMEI is numeric then:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "select HANDSET_SERIAL_NUMBER_NEW, SERVREQ_TRANSACTION_TS, " & _ 
    " from mi_tempadm.wome_tm_data_new where HANDSET_SERIAL_NUMBER_NEW  = " & IMEI
```

If not numeric then enclose with `'`

Don't forget to add a check in case of `RS.EOF` (no match found)

Try calling your function from a sub and any errors will be much more visible:

```
Sub testOracle()

   Debug.Print GetToadData(1234)

End sub
```

**Edit** - caching example (untested)

```vb
 Function GetToadData(IMEI)

    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Static cache as Object

    'create cache if not already created
    If cache Is Nothing Then Set cache = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    If Not cache.exists(IMEI) Then
        Conn.Open "PROVIDER=MSDAORA.Oracle;DATA SOURCE=XXXXX;" & _
                   "USER ID=XXXXX;PASSWORD=XXXXX"
        Cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
        Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
        Cmd.CommandText = " select HANDSET_SERIAL_NUMBER_NEW, SERVREQ_TRANSACTION_TS, " & _
                          " from mi_tempadm.wome_tm_data_new " & _
                          " where HANDSET_SERIAL_NUMBER_NEW=" & IMEI
        Set RS = Cmd.Execute
        If Not RS.EOF Then
            cache(IMEI) = RS.Fields(0).Value
        Else
            cache(IMEI) = "????"
        End If
    End If 'not cached

    GetToadData = cache(IMEI)


End Function
```

Comment: Tim - thank you!  I was missing the ' in my sql statement.  The suggestion about running the function through a sub was also a great help in debugging the code!  The formula in B1 was able to retrieve the date based on the cell value in A1.  So i copied the formula down to the end of the range... it sure does take a long time to retrieve the requested data!

Comment: You will find that the performance of a function like that is quite poor, and it may end up being executed multiple times as the workbook recalculates.  One thing you can do (if your data doesn't update frequently) is cache the result in a (eg) Scripting Dictionary so that you can skip repeated lookups on the same input.  see for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902879/formulas-to-be-triggered-when-excel-is-opened-or-saved/39903396#39903396